# Indefinite integral of product of exponential and Modified Bessel function with different arguments

Tags: indefinite-integrals, bessel-functions

I have found references (see for example https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.43) that the following equality holds
$$\int e^{-x}K_{0}(x)dx=xe^{-x}(K_{0}(x)-K_{1}(x))$$ (here $K_{n}$ denotes the modified Bessel function of the second kind of order $n$).

Does this give me any help to find
$$\int e^{-ax}K_{0}(x)dx,$$ with $a>0$?